# Grunt task to save mongoose object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, gruntjs

I'm trying to write a simple grunt task to save an object to a mongoose collection.  I'm having issues with the save command.  It's not printing out any errors or save messages.  I'm not sure why.  I have checked the collection through mongo shell and it is not saving.

```
var db = require('./db/schema');

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.registerTask('adduser', 'add a user to the database', function(usr) {
        var user = new db.userModel({ username: usr});

        console.log(user);
        user.save(function(err) {
          if(err) {
            console.log('error: ' + err);
          } else {
            console.log('saved user: ' + user.username);
          }
        });
  });

};
```

Output

```
$ grunt adduser:bob
Running "adduser:bob" (adduser) task
{ username: 'bob' }

Done, without errors.
```

The output should say 'error: error message' or 'saved user: bob'.  But this code is not being executed for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user.save` call is async, so you need to put the Grunt task into async mode as shown [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Creating-tasks#custom-tasks).

It should be something like this:

```js
grunt.registerTask('adduser', 'add a user to the database', function(usr) {
    var user = new db.userModel({ username: usr});

    // Invoke async mode
    var done = this.async();

    console.log(user);
    user.save(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log('error: ' + err);
      } else {
        console.log('saved user: ' + user.username);
      }

      // Signal to Grunt that the async task is complete.
      done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am now having a problem implementing a drop task.  Perhaps you could help?  It's a smilar error, and the connection is never closed and no output given.  grunt.registerTask('drop', 'drop the database', function() {
    var done = this.async();
    db.mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Successfully dropped db');
      }
      db.mongoose.connection.close(done);
    });

  });

Comment: I created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310627/grunt-task-to-drop-mongoose-database

Comment: How do you make the mongoose connection in Grunt?

Comment: @Imray It's best to post that as a new question.

Comment: When I Google "mongoose grunt" this comes up first. Isn't it a one line answer?