# Grunt task to drop mongoose database

Tags: asynchronous, mongoose, gruntjs

I'm trying to create a grunt task to drop a mongodb database through mongoose.  The connection is hanging and I have to force quit and it is not actually dropping the database or outputting an error.

```
var db = require('./db/schema');

grunt.registerTask('drop', 'drop the database', function() {
  // async mode
  var done = this.async();

  db.mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Successfully dropped db');
    }
    db.mongoose.connection.close(done);
  });

});
```

Output

```
$ grunt drop
Running "drop" task
Successfully connected to: mongodb://localhost/test
^C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution to my problems here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoose-orm/Cck_VND80r8  Had to wrap everything in connection.on

```
grunt.registerTask('drop', 'drop the database', function() {
// async mode
var done = this.async();

db.mongoose.connection.on('open', function () { 
  db.mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Successfully dropped db');
    }
    db.mongoose.connection.close(done);
  });
});
});
```